# C# stream server-generated PDFs to ZipArchive using a Pipe

Tags: c#, stream, blazor

I am using Blazor server (.net 6). Is there any way to stream the download of a zip archive? I'm generating a couple hundred PDFs and, instead of downloading them individually, they are stuffed into a zip archive, which is downloaded to the client once all the PDFs have been generated.

The problem is that the archive is stored in memory and this appears to be causing the server to occasionally run out of memory causing the process to fail. If I could stream the download, it should (?) relieve some of the memory pressure, at least that is my hope. While doing some reading, I encountered an [article](https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/create-zip-files-on-http-request-without-intermediate-files-using-aspdotnet-mvc-razor-pages-and-endpoints) that seems to accomplish this by using a C# Pipe. This is my first introduction to a Pipe and I have not been able to get the example to work in my scenario.

Here is what I have tried, based on the example given in the article:

```
try
{
    var pipe = new Pipe();
    using ( ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive( pipe.Writer.AsStream(), ZipArchiveMode.Create ) )
    {
        foreach ( var app in appList)
        {
            var document = new Document( app );
            var pdf = document.GeneratePdf();

            // Add the individual file (bytes) to the zip archive
            var entry = archive.CreateEntry( $"{app.FirstLastName}.pdf", System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.NoCompression );
            using ( var entryStream = entry.Open() )
            using ( var ms = new MemoryStream( pdf ) )
            {
                await ms.CopyToAsync( entryStream ); // This never completes, the application hangs here 
            }
        }
    }

    // Download the zip file
    await blazorDownloadFileService.DownloadFile( fileNameZip, pipe.Reader.AsStream(), ContentType.APPLICATIONOCTETSTREAM );
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    var msg = ex.Message;
    throw;
}
```

The code above doesn't produce an error, it just never completes.

So my questions are, is it possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish and if so, how? Am I even on the right track?

Comment: Are you sure that the writer stream has CanSeek == true? The article you point to does use a MemoryStream.

Answer (score 0):

It's hanging because a Pipe expects to be written and read concurrently, so that there is a constant flow of data. Otherwise the buffer fills and writing stops until it's emptied.

You need to do this as two separate tasks, and `await` both together.

```cs
async Task CreateZip(PipeWriter writer, List<string> appList)
{
    using var stream = writer.AsStream();
    using ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
    foreach ( var app in appList)
    {
        var document = new Document(app);
        var pdf = document.GeneratePdf();

        // Add the individual file (bytes) to the zip archive
        var entry = archive.CreateEntry( $"{app.FirstLastName}.pdf", System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.NoCompression );
        using var entryStream = entry.Open();
        using var ms = new MemoryStream(pdf);
        await ms.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
    }
}
```

```cs
var pipe = new Pipe();
using (var readStream = pipe.Reader.AsStream())
{
    var taskCreate = CreateZip(pipe.Writer, appList);
    var taskDownload = 
    // Download the zip file
        blazorDownloadFileService.DownloadFile(fileNameZip, readStream, ContentType.APPLICATIONOCTETSTREAM);
    await Task.WhenAll(taskCreate, taskDownload);
}
```

Having said that, it would also be more efficient to reuse the `MemoryStream` to create the PDF. For example, something like this

```
    using var ms = new MemoryStream();    
    foreach ( var app in appList)
    {
        var document = new Document(app);
        ms.SetLength(0);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var pdf = document.GeneratePdf(ms);
        // Add the individual file (bytes) to the zip archive
        var entry = archive.CreateEntry( $"{app.FirstLastName}.pdf", System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.NoCompression );
        using var entryStream = entry.Open();
        await ms.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
    }
```